# unable to stop stream when i DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to stop the stream when i close the jframe. i do not want to EXIT_ON_CLOSE beacuse i do not want to exit my application. When i use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE the frame closes but the audiostream keeps on playing. Is there a way to stop this stream without the use of some external button.(i want to close the stream just by clicking "X" on the jframe).
Thank you for help.

```
public class MediaPlayer {
    private JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame();
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent ourMediaPlayer;
    private String mediapath = "";

    MediaPlayer(String vlcPath,String mediaURL) {
        this.mediapath = mediaURL;
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcPath);
        ourMediaPlayer =  new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        ourFrame.setContentPane(ourMediaPlayer);
        ourFrame.setSize(1200, 800);
        ourFrame.setVisible(true);
        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run() {
        ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediapath);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add a WindowListener and close your audio stream in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle your stream closing operation on window close, with below:

```
   ouFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                // close/stop audio stream here
                System.out.println("closed");
            }
    });
```